# JavaScript permissions errors stemming from an IFrame

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee

I have a `.jsp` that contains an IFrame with a page that has some embedded JavaScript. This JavaScript accesses some DOM elements in the parent page (the one containing the IFrame).

The embedded page is going to be on a seperate sub-domain from the parent page, and I realize that there are some security implications. My impression is that the `document.domain` of any pages embedded in IFrames must match the document.domain of parent pages for cross-IFrame access to be allowed. The embedded page currently contains the following code to `broaden` the scope of its security:

```
document.domain = 'domain.com'; //where domain.com is my domain
```

It then proceeds to access DOM elements in the parent document.

I am currently testing this, and have modified the hosts file on the Windows machine serving the parent page with the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```

The goal is to trick JavaScript on the parent page into believing that the document in the embedded page is being served from the same domain.

If I then browse to the page on the same machine. Despite the `document.domain` showing up as `domain.com` in both my parent and embedded pages as observed through Firebug, I am getting 'Permission denied' errors when attempting to get or set DOM properties from JavaScript running in the embedded page.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the "document.domain" properties look the same, from [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196989(VS.85).aspx) is sounds like you still have to explicity set them to be the same:

> All the pages on different hosts must
>   have the domain property explicitly
>   set to the same value to communicate
>   successfully with each other. For
>   example, the value of the domain
>   property of a page on the host
>   microsoft.com is "microsoft.com" by
>   default. It might seem logical that if
>   you set the domain property of a page
>   on another host named
>   msdn.microsoft.com to "microsoft.com,"
>   that the two pages could communicate
>   with each other. However, this is not
>   the case, **unless you explicitly set
>   the domain property of the page on
>   microsoft.com to "microsoft.com."**

Comment: I believe you are correct. I tried explicitly setting the the document.domain property in the JavaScript code to the same value I have in my hosts file. Once I did this, the errors were resolved.

This is very strange, however. I observed the value of the document.domain property before explicitly setting it and after, and the value was unchanged. Yet, somehow this caused everything to work. Perhaps there is something else going on that I am not aware of that is resolved by setting this property in the code.

Comment: The link you posted is very helpful as well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you could put a proxy to redirect requests of `<iframe src="http://domain.com/fake/">` to the right place.

It's just an idea...

Regards.